# Flash AS3 - Ball Physics (fast move and small objects on path)

Tags: actionscript-3

After read a lot about ball physics, watch some examples and few days of trying making pinball with bitmaps, I need help. I use simple (easy to work with) and fast performance Physics AS3 engine for bitmaps http://coreyoneil.com/portfolio/index.php?project=5 but still cant fix following problem:  if ball is moving too fast and object on path is too small, there will be no collision detection (code works perfect only with bigger objects or if ball is moving slower). I am not good at physics and maths. Here is function code which make physics for ball on every frame rate (but maybe its better to change it to setTimeout):

```
    function showFrame(e:Event) // onEnterFrame
    {
        var collisions:Array = collisionlist.checkCollisions();
        if(collisions.length) // if collision
        {
            var collision:Object = collisions[0]; // get collision information
            var angle:Number = collision.angle; // get collision angle
            var overlap:int = collision.overlapping.length; // get collision overlap
            var sin:Number = Math.sin(angle);
            var cos:Number = Math.cos(angle);
            var vx0:Number = vx * cos + vy * sin;
            var vy0:Number = vy * cos - vx * sin;
            vx0 = ((mass - immovable) * vx0) / (mass + immovable); // var immovable:Number=10000; var mass:Number=immovable*2;
            vx = vx0 * cos - vy0 * sin;
            vy = vy0 * cos + vx0 * sin;
            vx -= cos * overlap / radius; // radius=Math.round(ball.width/2);
            vy -= sin * overlap / radius;
            vx += speed; // var speed:Number=0;
        }           
        vy += gravity; // var gravity:Number=0.75;
        vy *= friction; // var friction:Number=0.981;
        vx *= friction;
        ball.x += vx;
        ball.y += vy;
        //setTimeout(showFrame, 20);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use sub steps.

Its simple but works nicely, basically you divide your velocities by how many steps you want, then have a for loop that tests for collisions on those increments.

Here is a good example/tutorial: http://www.samclifton.com/tutorials.php?tut=2

Comment: Very useful. I should change mass into value 1, cause ball sometimes stuck (now it bounces much more). I need to test it better, but current code is now capable for collision with 1 pixel objects at any move. I will post current code change with credits.

Comment: Awesome, the only thing to keep in mind is that after doing this for a game world (5 to 20+ objects) it can take a little bit of performance. So if you had 10 objects with collisions and you want 5 steps, you would make 50 collision tests per frame.

Answer (score 0):

Yah so the problem is probably that your calculations are allowing it to move beyond the point where it would collide when you turn up the speed.  So what you can do is increase the framerate or like you said use a timer to do this logic in the background and allow the framerate to remain the same, then reduce your velocities or gravity or whatever you need to do to get it moving at a reasonable speed and not allowing parts to jump past one another.